# How can I roll up a line to get a circle?

Tags: code-request, code-review

I am trying to transfer n1=4 points that I have on a line, on a circle. suppose:

```
l1 = {{1.7320508075688772`, 0.`}, {3.4641016151377544`, 0.`}, {5.196152422706632`, 0.`}, {6.928203230275509`, 0.`}};

n1=4;
```

So we can define the radius as :

```
radius=n1/(2. \[Pi]);
```

having the x,y positions of the points and the radius, I should be able to define the new positions of my points on the ring:

```
  ring1 = Chop[Table[{x2d, y2d} = l1[[i]];
 theta1 = N[(x2d 2 \[Pi])/n1];
 {radius*Cos[theta1], radius*Sin[theta1], y2d}, {i, 1, 4}]];
```

I am expecting my points to be at equal distance (pi/4) on the circle, but they seem end up on different places with different distancing than what I expect.

I am asking this question becuase I will be adding another ring on top of this, and I want to rotate the second ring such that it's points end up in the middle of the first one.

Can any one help me with this please?

The shape I want to eventually create is (I got these datapoints from a tube another sofware generated, and I want produce a code that can replicate these data points):

```
fring={{0,10.115`,12.161`},{0,10.115`,12.931`},{0,10.115`,12.931`},{0,10.353`,11.428`},{0,10.353`,13.663`},{0,10.353`,13.663`},{0,10.805`,10.805`},{0,10.805`,14.286`},{0,10.805`,14.286`},{0,11.428`,10.353`},{0,11.428`,14.739`},{0,11.428`,14.739`},{0,12.161`,10.115`},{0,12.161`,14.976`},{0,12.161`,14.976`},{0,12.931`,10.115`},{0,12.931`,14.976`},{0,12.931`,14.976`},{0,13.663`,10.353`},{0,13.663`,14.739`},{0,13.663`,14.739`},{0,14.286`,10.805`},{0,14.286`,14.286`},{0,14.286`,14.286`},{0,14.739`,11.428`},{0,14.739`,13.663`},{0,14.739`,13.663`},{0,14.976`,12.161`},{0,14.976`,12.931`},{0,14.976`,12.931`},{0.1,10.085`,12.546`},{0.1,10.205`,11.785`},{0.1,10.205`,13.306`},{0.1,10.555`,11.099`},{0.1,10.555`,13.992`},{0.1,11.099`,10.555`},{0.1,11.099`,14.537`},{0.1,11.785`,10.205`},{0.1,11.785`,14.886`},{0.1,12.546`,10.085`},{0.1,12.546`,15.007`},{0.1,13.306`,10.205`},{0.1,13.306`,14.886`},{0.1,13.992`,10.555`},{0.1,13.992`,14.537`},{0.1,14.537`,11.099`},{0.1,14.537`,13.992`},{0.1,14.886`,11.785`},{0.1,14.886`,13.306`},{0.1,15.007`,12.546`}};
```

---

This is added for clarity about my ultimate goal:

So my altimate goal is to produce a cylinder with triangular lattice pattern :

As MarcoB suggested It is easier to use CirclePoints. I tried to create a circle with 4 points in x-y plane at z=o.I created the second circle the same as first one in x-y plane, but rotate it by 45 degree with respect to the first one and put it at z=0.77 , now I can call this a ring which consists of two circles on top of eachother creating a very short tube with triangular lattice points.But I need to create a larger tube with the same pattern.

for just two circles it is easy:

```
 c1 = CirclePoints[{radf, 0}, 4];
 c1 = Table[Insert[c1[[i]], 0, 3], {i, 1, Length[c1]}];
 
 m=0.77
 c2 = CirclePoints[{radf, \[Pi]/4}, 4];
 c2 = Table[Insert[c2[[i]], m, 3], {i, 1, Length[c2]}]

 ring1=Join[c1, c2];
 p = ListPointPlot3D[ring1]
```

The next step is stacking these rings on top of eachother to get a cylinder with a trangular lattice pattern.

So this is what I want. but I need to stack more rings on top of eachother.  Could you please help me making this cylinder?

Comment: Could you explain the ultimate goal in some more detail? There may be easier alternative approaches. Would `CirclePoints` help here?

Comment: Thank you so much Marco. I'm giving some more explanation in the question. I am very thankful if you can help me.

Comment: Uncertain ultimate aim:  In case relevant :[here](https://ubpdqnmathematica.wordpress.com/2023/05/04/string-around-a-circle/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have some equidistant x values you want to map onto a cricle with given radius, so that the last point is at angle 2 Pi:

Toward this end, we first define the points and the max x value and the radius:

```
n1 = 4;
l1 = {{1.7320508075688772`, 0.`}, {3.4641016151377544`, 
    0.`}, {5.196152422706632`, 0.`}, {6.928203230275509`, 0.`}};
radius = n1/(2. \[Pi]);
xmax = Max[l1[[All, 1]]];
```

Now we define a mapping function that maps the x values onto the circle:

```
map[x_, xmax_, rad_] := Module[{phi},
  phi = 2 Pi  x/xmax;
  radius {Cos[phi], Sin[phi]}
  ]
```

With this we may create the circle points and draw them :

```
pts = map[#, xmax, radius] & /@ l1[[All, 1]] // Chop;
Graphics[{Circle[{0, 0}, radius], Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[pts]}]
```

[image]